# Django forms - RadioSelect on fly

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a problem with django and forms.

In forms.py I have sth like this:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.answers = kwargs.pop('answers')
    super(AnswersForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    choices = ["aaaa", "ssssssssss", "ddddddddd"]
    self.fields['answers'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices = choices, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

And when i use it in template, I have sth like this:

```
Answers:

- a
- s
- d
```

Do you know why I haven't got all words, but only one letter of the word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`choices` should be a list (or other iterable) of two-tuples. The first entry in each tuple is  the value that gets stored in the database. The second is the human-readable name.
See the documentation on [`choices`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#field-choices) for more information.

Thus, your `choices` list should look more like this:

```
choices = [("a","aaaa"), ("s", "ssssssssss"), ("d", "ddddddddd")]
```

As posted, your code is considering each string (aaaa, ssssssss, etc.) to be tuple-like and grabbing the *first letter* of each for the database representation, and the *second letter* of each for the human-readable name (used for the label).